# the alert inside my success function response on ajax wont appear?

Tags: ajax

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response){
                        alert("success"); --> this is the one

                    }
                });
```

I've successfully inserted the data from my sign-up form i just want to inform the user that they successfully registered on the alert box

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not succeeding. Have you tried throwing in an error handler to see if it's failing?

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(response){
    alert("success"); --> this is the one
  },
  error: function (XHR, status, error){
    console.log('error', error);
  }
});
```

Comment: thats what i thought but i can insert the data from my form to my database with validation. its fine i check the console it says xmlhttprequest cannot i think maybe because of that error on the console. by the way how can i do that throwing an error handler

Comment: @Lestah check out my revised answer with snippet

Comment: ive added the code on to my ajax and i check the console where can i find if there is an error

Comment: Can you post the previous error that was on the console?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[::1]/ci_testblog/index.php/login/addUsers. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. this is the only error i encountered on the console